# Half bridge inverter

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-design, power-electronics, inverter

[image: Mosfet driver circuit]

I am using this driver IC, UCC21220, for half bridge inverter circuit. I am making a simple sine wave inverter. Two N-Channel MOSFETS are connected in series as can be seen in the diagram attached. I want to switch these two MOSFETs.

How is the upper N-Channel MOSFET switched ON when its source is in a floating state (because the lower MOSFET is OFF, so how is it switching ON)? I want to understand the complete configuration of half bridge inverter using this IC UCC21220a.

Comment: The gate voltage comes from cboot. Cboot is charged by the switching action. The datasheet should explain this as there are limitations that need to be considered.

Comment: Search for bootstrapping technique. When the lower mosfet is ON, the bootstrap cap is being charged.

Comment: its a bootstrap circuit with all the limitations associated with such a scheme... ie the TOP switch is uncontrollable until the BOTTOM switch is switched on and equally regularly switched

Comment: Can I give -12V at VSSB pin 9 ? How will I then drive the lower N channel mosfet ? 0V at VDDB ?

Answer (score 1):

When the bottom MOSFET is on, it connects the switching node (VSSA) to ground.
The bootstrap capacitor (Cboot) will charge to (almost) VDD level trough Rboot and the series bootstrap diode.

When the top MOSFET has to turn on, the chip will connect VDDA to OUTA, thereby placing Cboot in parallel to the top MOSFET's gate-source. This turns the MOSFET on. As the switching node voltage starts to rise, Cboot will "ride up" with it, because it is referenced to the switching node. Thus the MOSFET gate-source voltage equals the voltage on Cboot, regardless of whatever voltage level the switching node is to ground.

An obvious limitation is that Cboot needs to recharge periodically. So this scheme cannot be used to keep the top MOSFET on indefinately (100% duty cycle is impossible).

Comment: Can I give -12V at VSSB pin 9 ? How will I then drive the lower N channel mosfet ? 0V at VDDB ?